# How to include the soap envelope tag when marshalling using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I am marshalling a soap request using JAXB. It is working but the resulting XML does not contain the `soap:Envelope` tag. Also, the namespace is indicated on root element instead of inside the `soap:Envelope` tag. There is also an additional `standalone` attribute on the xml tag. How can I achieved an output similar to the 2nd XML below using JAXB's marshaller?

Currently, here's how my marshalled XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customer xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">
    <ns:id>201200001</ns:id>
    <ns:name>Name</ns:name>
    <ns:age>18</ns:age>
</Customer>
```

And here is how I want it to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">   
    <soap:Body xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org/beanLevel1Namespace" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/beanLevel2Namespace">
        <ns:Customer>
            <ns1:id>201200001</ns:id>
            <ns1:name>Name</ns:name>
            <ns1:age>18</ns:age>
        </ns:Customer>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why do you need Envelope in your xml? Also, how does it matter if namespace is present at the root level or at Envelope?

Comment: @sreehari: It needs to be inside an envelope because I'm going to send it as a soap request. Regarding the position of the namespace, I'm not really sure if its position matters. The namespace on the sample request that I have here is located inside the envelope so I'm following it just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Why would you not use JAX-WS for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your XML inside an Envelope before sending.

```
"<Envelope><Body>" + your_xml + "</Body></Envelope>
```

Always keep your namespace at the element level; not at Envelope level. Because you get clarity when looking at an element what type it is. It doesn't matter where you keep the namespace.

There's a problem with your marshalled XML. Correct XML is:

```
<ns:Customer xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">
    <ns:id>201200001</ns:id>
    <ns:name>Name</ns:name>
    <ns:age>18</ns:age>
</ns:Customer>
```

Again, it doesn't matter where you put the namespace declaration:

```
<ns:Customer xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">
    <ns:id>201200001</ns:id>
</ns:Customer>

<Customer xmlns="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">
    <id>201200001</id>
</Customer>

<ns1:Customer xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">
    <ns2:id xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/beanLevelNamespace">201200001</ns2:id>
</ns1:Customer>
```

They are all same.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there is a way to set JAXB to also produce the soap envelope? Or is there no such setting on JAXB? Also if I simply add the soap tags on the marshalled xml, the <?xml..?> tag will be included inside the soap envelope. Can I set JAXB not to include the <?xml..?> tag on the generated xml?

Comment: JAX-B is an XML processing API. It can process any XML. For invoking a Web service you will user another API - preferably JAX-WS. Don't mix these two things. Why do you want to deal with SOAP Envelop in your code? This will be done behind scends by JAX-WS.

Comment: We already have a class for invoking a web service. However, it only acts as a connector to the web service. For it to work, the whole SOAP envelope and the contents of the envelope must be passed to said class. As such, I need to create the SOAP envelop together with the envelope's contents and pass it to the said class. We're not using JAX-WS.